# what is the lowelink mean of Tarjan's algorithm

Tags: graph

I was reading the description of [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for finding the strongly connected components in a driected graph.
But I find it hard to understand these codes snippet:

```
 if (w.index is undefined) then
        // Successor w has not yet been visited; recurse on it
        strongconnect(w)
        v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
      else if (w is in S) then
        // Successor w is in stack S and hence in the current SCC
        v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index)
      end if
```

the fourth and the seventh lines are different, this make me confused.
And in my opinion,the seveth line could write as the same way with the fourth line
`v.lowkink := min(v.lowlink, w.index)`

I test this in my program and it works fine, and for me, it's better to understand bcz verdex v cloud reach hight up root, but i couldn't prove itT_T.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a program that enumerated all graphs of size 4, then run each version (with either `min(v.lowlink, w.index)` or `min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)` if w is in S) and compared the results. Both were exactly identical in all cases, even though w.lowlink and w.index were often different.

The reason why we can use w.index is this: consider where on the stack S relative to the current node v the other node w is.

If it's earlier on the stack then it has a smaller index than the current node (because it was visited earlier, duh), so the current node is not the "head" of its connected component and that would be reflected in v.lowlink <= w.index < v.index anyway. And it's not like w.lowlink has any particular meaning at this point either, it's in the progress of being computed and doesn't necessarily have its final value yet.

Now, if w is later in the stack than v, then the crucial property that the algorithm depends on is that then w is a descendant of v, not some sibling/cousing node still left there from an earlier recursive call. Or, as it is usually stated in a complete proof, strongly connected components never span several unconnected branches of our search tree (forest). Because since it's an SCC, there must be a path from w to v, and since we are enumerating stuff in a depth-first order, we must have visited v using that path from w before we have finished processing w, so w should be earlier in the stack than v!

And if w is a descendant of v then we already got its actual lowlink value the first time we visited it and are not interested in it any more.

On a side note, it's trivial to get rid of the lowlink property on nodes and make strongconnect return it directly. Then we wouldn't be tempted to check it instead of w.index in the second case =)